# Android - addJavascriptInterface() only works when added in the same class where WebView is created

Tags: unit-testing, testing, webview

I am having trouble using addJavascriptInterface() in an Instrumentation test case. I have access to a web view and I want to inject javascript using an interface. Injecting javascript without an interface works fine. Also when I add the interface in the same class where webview is initially created it works and I am able to call java methods from javascript. How can I get addJavascriptInterface() to work in a test case or in a different class to the class where it was created.

Comment: Are you calling addJavascriptInterface() after the WebView has finished loading its content? I think that the Javascript interface object may not be available until the WebView loads new content. See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)